# Cannot Deserialize Non-Ascii in Json String

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Everytime I try to deserialize a string that contains a non ASCII character (with .netcore3.1's JsonSerializer), I do not get the correct result back. For example, when this is the string

```
{
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "languages": ["German","English","Spanish","French","Italian","Dutch","Portuguese","Russian","Japanese","Chinese (simplified)","Esperanto","Lojban"],
    "languages_local": ["Deutsch","English","Espa├▒ol","Fran├ºais","Italiano","Nederlands","Portugu├¬s","╤Ç╤â╤ü╤ü╨║╨╕╨╣ ╤Å╨╖╤ï╨║","µùÑµ£¼Φ¬₧","τ«ÇΣ╜ôΣ╕¡µûç (Σ╕¡σ¢╜)","Esperanto","Lojban"]
  }
}
```

What changes do I need to make to be able to deserialize this with JsonDeserializer?

I looked at `JsonSerializationOptions`'s `Encoder` properties, but nothing worked when I played with it.

I'm attempting to deserialize it into the following class (LanguagesResponse)

```
    public class LanguagesResponse : RpcResponse
    {
        public LanguagesResult result { get; set; }
    }

    public class LanguagesResult
    {
        public List<string> languages = new List<string>();
        public List<string> languages_local = new List<string>();
    }
```

Where RpcResponse is `string id` and `string jsonrpc`

When I receive the response, I'm deserializing as such:

```
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            using Stream ms = new MemoryStream(responseBody);
            var serializationOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions()
            {
                IgnoreNullValues = true,
                Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping,
            };
            LanguagesResponse responseObject = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<LanguagesResponse>(ms, serializationOptions, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `ReadAsStringAsync` which should use the encoding included in the response (if one is included).

Comment: @ckuri What if an encoding isn't specified?

Comment: It would fallback to UTF-8, which is also the default encoding of JsonSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass a `MemoryStream` to `DeserializeAsync`.  (That will work only if the content is ASCII, because that's the only encoding where the string is identical to the byte array.)

Pass a string instead, which you can get with:

```
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms);
```

That is, assuming your content is UTF-8 encoded.  You need to find out.  If it's another encoding, use that instead of `Encoding.UTF8`.

**EDIT**:

You actually don't need to find out what encoding is and hardcode it (e.g. `Encoding.UTF8`). You can use this line instead, which will get the encoding from the response:

```
string s = response.ContentEncoding.GetString(ms);
```

However, poorly written API's may not include the encoding in the response and you will have to hard-code it to get it to work.

Comment: There is no ContentEncoding on the response object.

Comment: try `ContentType`